# Conversion failed when converting varchar to data type int... but field is varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error on the 2nd line running the below code

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'apple' to data
> type int

```
create table ##temp (FieldA numeric(20,10), FieldB numeric(20,10), FieldC varchar(255))

insert into ##temp values(1.1, 2.1, 3.1), (4.1, 5.1, 6.1), ('apple', 'pear', 'orange')
```

Why does it expect an int when varchar is specified when making the table?

Comment: Uhhhh . . . I'm lost.  You defined the column as `numeric`.  There are no surprises here.

Comment: You are doing insert row by row, not column by column.

Comment: Note that in SQL, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: That SQL won't produce that error, there are **no** `int` data types involved. That doesn't change that the way you have defined your [`VALUES` Table Construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is wrong, however, but if you *are* getting that error above there's something *else* aren't telling us.

Comment: `('apple', 'pear', 'orange')` This is a complete row that you are trying to insert into your table. Obviously you cannot store 'apple' or 'pear' in a numeric datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing rows and columns.  You want:

```
insert into ##temp (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC)
    values (1.1, 4.1, 'apple'),
           (2.1, 5.1, 'pear'),
           (3.1, 6.1, 'orange');
```

Each parenthesized expression for `values` is a *row* not the values in one column.

Also note that I included the column names for the insert.  This is a best practice.